Setting On in dropdown semantic ui don´t work
I'm trying in my dropdown, which already works, allowing it to only perform the search when the "Search" button is clicked.
I saw in the semantic Ui documentation that there is an "On" option that can help me with the click event
https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/settings
I thought using: On: $(#myButton).click() could solve my problem but that doesn't seem to be the case.
cshtml
<div id="idDrop" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown"">
    <input class="search">
    <i class="search icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="ui button bgm-wine-bnb icon labeled" type="button" id="btnSearch">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        Buscar
    </button>
</div>

JS
$("#idDrop").dropdown({
     fullTextSearch: 'exact',
     on: $('#btnSearch').click(),
     apiSettings: {
         cache: false,
         saveRemoteData: false,
         url: ROOT_URL + '/url/url?query={query}',
         onResponse: function (response) {
            -- do some stuffs       
             return response;
         }
     },
     minCharacters: 4,
     interruptRequests: false,
     filterRemoteData: false,
     localSearch: false,
     onChange: function (value, text, $choice) {
         -- do some stuffs
     }
 });

Is there anything I can do in this case or in any other way?
I need to do the research and request only when the button is clicked

please create a minimal reproducible example
